# How to run a java class(application) on rest class?

Tags: java, rest

The REST class is as follows:

```
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public GenericResource() {
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getXml() {
        return "App Running";
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String postXml(String param) {
        ImagesBean imagesBean = new ImagesBean();
        imagesBean.fillValues(param);
     //TODO call and Run my application RunService.java
     //ParamWrapper.wrapParams(param);
        return "return post " + param;
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of GenericResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void putXml(String content) {
    }
}
```

So I want to run my java class called RunService.java on the REST class. How do I implement this? The java class contains a service to format pictures found on my server.

Comment: Run your REST class inside the application server like Jetty or Tomcat.

Comment: Shouldn't the REST class contain a method to call the java class? The REST class runs on Tomcat.

Comment: If you want to write a standalone client, your class will be a normal java class with the main method. and you can use that class to execute the rest endpoint.

Comment: After adding the main method to the REST java class, can I call it using a GET reguest. if so how to do that?